# Map drive letter to VolumeID

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I've received the complaint...

> Help! My `I` drive filled up on `EC2-Server-1`! Please give moar space!

However, when I remote on the the server before extending the volume, I find I cannot easily figure out *which* EBS volume I will need to extend.

When I run `aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=EC2-Server-1"`, the relevant info found in `$.Reservations.Instances.BlockDeviceMappings` shows...

```
DeviceName Ebs
---------- ---
/dev/sda1  @{VolumeId=vol-0123;...}
xvdf       @{VolumeId=vol-0456;...}
xvdj       @{VolumeId=vol-0789;...}
xvdg       @{VolumeId=vol-0abc;...}
...
```

Following [this guidance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html), I can see in <kbd>Disk Management</kbd> under <kbd>Properties > General</kbd> for **Disk 2** (Drive Letter `I`) the <kbd>Location</kbd> value is `Bus Number 0, Target Id 6, LUN 0`. Looking this value up on the [windows volume mapping table](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html#windows-volume-mapping) from the same page, we see the corresponding `DeviceName` is `xvdg`, which maps to `vol-0abc`.

So... great... now I just need to click through about 5 dialogue boxes every time I need to do this (or just fuzzy match on size from the AWS Console and Windows Explorer).

#### Is there terminal command (or series of commands) I can execute to retrieve this mapping quickly & reliably?

I'm currently rubber ducking my way through various `wmic` iterations, but... any chance this is a solved problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [below function](https://gist.github.com/petervandivier/4361245a2846d7d37edd04299e045c44) returns `BlockDeviceName` and EBS `VolumeID` for a given drive letter when executed within the context of an EC2 host. It handles for drives that span multiple disks, but not for disks spanning multiple EBS volumes.

```perl
function Get-EbsDeets {
    [cmdletbinding()]Param(
        [string[]]$DriveLetter
    )

    # $wmiVol = Get-WmiObject Win32_Volume      | Where DriveLetter -eq "$DriveLetter`:"
    $wmiLd = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk | Where {($_.DeviceID).Trim(':') -in $DriveLetter}

    $wmiLd | ForEach-Object {
        $Letter =  $_.DeviceID

        $wmiLd2p = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition | Where Dependent -in $_.__PATH

        $wmiDd2p = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition | Where Dependent -in $wmiLd2p.Antecedent

        $wmiDsk = Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | Where __PATH -in $wmiDd2p.Antecedent 

        $wmiDsk | ForEach-Object {
            $EstimatedVolumeId = $_.SerialNumber.Insert(3,'-')
            $DeviceName = (ec2WinVolMap $_.SCSIBus -target $_.SCSITargetId -lun $_.SCSILogicalUnit).DeviceName
            $VolumeType = (ec2WinVolMap $_.SCSIBus -target $_.SCSITargetId -lun $_.SCSILogicalUnit).VolumeType
            $SizeGb = [Math]::Round(($_.Size / 1gb),2)

            [PSCustomObject]@{
                DriveLetter = $Letter 
                DiskNumber  = $_.DeviceId
                DeviceName  = $DeviceName
                VolumeType  = $VolumeType
                VolumeId    = $EstimatedVolumeId
                SizeGb      = $SizeGb
            }
        }
    }
}

Function ec2WinVolMap {
    [cmdletBinding()]Param(
         $bus
        ,$target
        ,$lun
    )
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html#windows-volume-mapping
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/InstanceStorage.html
    $Lookup = @"
Bus,Target,LUN,DeviceName,VolumeType
0,0,0,/dev/sda1,ebs
0,1,0,xvdb, ebs
0,2,0,xvdc, ebs
0,3,0,xvdd, ebs
0,4,0,xvde, ebs
0,5,0,xvdf, ebs
0,6,0,xvdg, ebs
0,7,0,xvdh, ebs
0,8,0,xvdi, ebs
0,9,0,xvdj, ebs
0,10,0,xvdk,ebs
0,11,0,xvdl,ebs
0,12,0,xvdm,ebs
0,13,0,xvdn,ebs
0,14,0,xvdo,ebs
0,15,0,xvdp,ebs
0,16,0,xvdq,ebs
0,17,0,xvdr,ebs
0,18,0,xvds,ebs
0,19,0,xvdt,ebs
0,20,0,xvdu,ebs
0,21,0,xvdv,ebs
0,22,0,xvdw,ebs
0,23,0,xvdx,ebs
0,24,0,xvdy,ebs
0,25,0,xvdz,ebs
0,78,0,xvdca,instance-store
0,79,0,xvdcb,instance-store
0,80,0,xvdcc,instance-store
0,81,0,xvdcd,instance-store
0,82,0,xvdce,instance-store
0,83,0,xvdcf,instance-store
0,84,0,xvdcg,instance-store
0,85,0,xvdch,instance-store
0,86,0,xvdci,instance-store
0,87,0,xvdcj,instance-store
0,88,0,xvdck,instance-store
0,89,0,xvdcl,instance-store
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

    $DeviceName = ($Lookup | Where-Object {
        $_.Bus    -eq $bus    -and `
        $_.Target -eq $target -and `
        $_.LUN    -eq $lun
    }).DeviceName

    $VolumeType = ($Lookup | Where-Object {
        $_.Bus    -eq $bus    -and `
        $_.Target -eq $target -and `
        $_.LUN    -eq $lun
    }).VolumeType

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        DeviceName = $DeviceName
        VolumeType = $VolumeType
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

Given the above limitation, you can estimate the EBS `VolumeID` for <sup>(the first volume in)</sup> a given disk by inspecting the `SerialNumber` attribute on [`Win32_DiskDrive`](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/Win32_DiskDrive/). As noted in [`@bjoster`'s answer](https://serverfault.com/a/954871/401889), you can also retrieve the bus, target, and lun values necessary to look up the `BlockDeviceName` based on the table in the previously linked [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-volumes.html#windows-volume-mapping).

Frustratingly though, this doesn't easily map back to the actual drive *letter* or *name* which you're likely to receive in an actual user complaint. To associate these attributes (found on the [`Win32_LogicalDisk`](http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/Win32_LogicalDisk/#properties) collection in my case), you can daisy chain back through the antecedent/dependent mappings on the `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition` and `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` collections.

When cobbling this together, I noted that on my installation `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` maps 1:1 for disks. While `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition` does match the number of EBS volumes (in the case of multiple volumes per disk), I haven't bothered just yet to figure out how to associate the bus, target, and lun needed to get the `BlockDeviceName` for the non-primary underlying volume(s) when they exist. If these are retrieved but for some reason the EBS `VolumeID` isn't immediately known for the non-primary volumes, there may be some thought of calling the AWSPowerShell function in the following way

```perl
$bdn = 'xvdg'

# assuming you've tagged your instance with the hostname
$ec2 = Get-EC2Instance -Filter @{Name='tag:Name';Values='EC2-Server-1'}

($ec2.Instances.BlockDeviceMappings | Where DeviceName -eq $bdn).Ebs
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. PowerShell (with WMI) to the rescue:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_DiskDrive | select-object DeviceID,size,scsiport,scsibus,scsitargetid,scsilogicalunit
```

This will leave you with:

```
DeviceID        : \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE9
size            : 234362882560
scsiport        : 3
scsibus         : 0
scsitargetid    : 2
scsilogicalunit : 4
```

Comment: Thanks! This is super helpful, but still seems to be missing a key bit needed to map `Win32_DiskDrive` (AWS info) to `Win32_Volume` (Drive Letter & Name).